# Run all Grunt SubTasks except one

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I've a bunch of subtasks for grunt watch (e.g. grunt watch:styles, grunt watch:sprites, etc). Then many other tasks run `grunt watch`. I would like to exclude one task. Is there a way to specify that? Basically run all `grunt watch` subtasks except `grunt watch:dist`.

I know I could create another task and only specify the subtasks I'm actually interested on, however, if I add another subtask later, that means now I've to add it, so I would rather not do it that way.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There might be a better way, but this is doing the trick for now:

```
grunt.registerTask('watch:basic', function () {
    delete grunt.config.data.watch.dist;
    grunt.task.run('watch');
});
```

Fortunately, in this case, I don't have other tasks that might run `grunt watch:dist`, so it's safe to simply remove the config, but I can think of other cases where this approach would create conflicts.

Comment: This is the way it worked for me: `delete grunt.config.data.watch.dist;`